# Define the graphics path in the header for TeXstudio

Tags: graphics, texstudio, paths, javascript, environment-variables

TeXstudio opens a preview, when the mouse cursor hovers the `\includegraphics` command.

Unfortunately this does not work, if a `graphicspath` is set for the document. It seems that TeXstudio 2.12.4 does not interpret this command.

```
\graphicspath{{/home/alice/mybook/gfx/}}
```

I found an option to configure **a search path for all documents** in TeXstudio.

[image: global configuration in TeXstudio]

How can I configure the search path per document? 
The most obvious way would be to add something like

```
% !TeX graphicspath = "/home/alice/mybook/gfx/" %<- does not work
```

is there a similar solution, or can I set it via Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration per document is currently not possible. This is an [open feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1151/).